# PHP Mysql - Generating a category with sub-categories loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, categories

Seeking some help with better PHP code that allows me to generate a list of categories with sub-categories, but print this across three columns.

First the table data (demonstration table only - although the table name and column names are correct):

```
--- TABLE NAME = walkthroughs ---

---------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | name                  | url           | cluster       |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  | A Room with a View    | http://...    | Happyville    |
|  2  | An Outdoor Tower      | http://...    | Happyville    |
|  3  | An Old Cottage        | http://...    | Happyville    |
|  4  | Town Hall             | http://...    | Misty Vale    |
|  5  | Cathedral             | http://...    | Misty Vale    |
|  6  | Babbling Brook        | http://...    | Old Forest    |
|  7  | The Lonely Flower     | http://...    | Old Forest    |
|  8  | The Hollow Tree       | http://...    | Old Forest    |
|  9  | The Secret Garden     | http://...    | Old Forest    |
| 10  | The Forgotten Corale  | http://...    | Open Plains   |
| 11  | Echo Caverns          | http://...    | Mountains     |
| 12  | The Forgotten Corale  | http://...    | Mountains     |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have played with PHP code that creates a 'cluster' category, and lists the related names and urls beneath it. It's messy, but does the job! The HTML output of this code is all in 1 column.

```
--- HTML OUTPUT ---

<h2>Happyville</h2>
<a href="url"> A Room with a View </a>
<a href="url"> An Outdoor Tower </a>
<a href="url"> An Old Cottage </a>
<br>
<h2>Misty Vale</h2>
<a href="url"> Town Hall </a>
<a href="url"> Cathedral </a>
<br>
<h2>Old Forest</h2>
<a href="url"> Babbling Brook </a>
<a href="url"> The Lonely Flower </a>
<a href="url"> The Hollow Tree </a>
<a href="url"> The Secret Garden </a>
<br>
<h2>Open Plains</h2>
<a href="url"> Babbling Brook </a>
<br>
<h2>Mountains</h2>
<a href="url"> Echo Caverns </a>
<a href="url"> The Forgotton Corale </a>
```

What I am looking for help with is the PHP for Mysql:

- So that the results are GROUPED BY the 'cluster' field,
- A unique value for the 'cluster' field is printed first, followed by all of the 'name' and 'url' values for that value,
- A PHP/Mysql count that can be used to divide the results into 3 columns.

Optimal HTML output appears below.

```
--- HTML OUTPUT ---
<div id="col-1">
  <h2>Happyville</div>
  <a href="url"> A Room with a View </a>
  <a href="url"> An Outdoor Tower </a>
  <a href="url"> An Old Cottage </a>
  <br>
  <h2>Misty Vale</h2>
  <a href="url"> Town Hall </a>
  <a href="url"> Cathedral </a>
  <br>
<div>
<div id="col-2">
  <h2>Old Forest</h2>
  <a href="url"> Babbling Brook </a>
  <a href="url"> The Lonely Flower </a>
  <a href="url"> The Hollow Tree </a>
  <a href="url"> The Secret Garden </a>
  <br>
  <h2>Open Plains</h2>
  <a href="url"> Babbling Brook </a>
  <br>
</div>
<div id="col-3">  
  <h2>Mountains</h2>
  <a href="url"> Echo Caverns </a>
  <a href="url"> The Forgotton Corale </a>
  <br>
</div>
```

Here's the current PHP I have been using, which I know is messy (i.e. I am uncertain about using arrays, for example), and while it can divide the results into 3 columns, it prints a heading and the 1st value, and then any further results appear in the next column (or not at all, in the case of column 3).

A live example of the issue can be found @ http://freethedangler.com/test/walkthroughs/instances-test.php (yes, it's a geeky MMO page!).

Note that the 'cluster' field is named 'cluster_or_campaigns' on the live example. I simplified the name here to make life easier.

```
--- CURRENT PHP ---
<?php
include("../php/lotrodb.php");

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$queryc="SELECT * FROM walkthroughs ORDER BY cluster ASC";
$queryd="SELECT cluster,COUNT(DISTINCT(cluster)) FROM walkthroughs GROUP BY cluster";
$resultc=mysql_query($queryc);
$resultd=mysql_query($queryd);

$numc=mysql_numrows($resultc);
$numd=mysql_numrows($resultd); // used to count the number of unique values for the 'cluster' field

mysql_close();

$i=0; //$i = counter used to count queryc values 
$j=0; //$j = counter used to print out <h2>'cluster'</h2> heading

$x=0;         //$x = counter used to count queryd values
$y=($numd/3); //$y = 1/3rd of $numd - used to close a column and start a new column
$z=$y*2;      //$z = 2/3rds of $numd - used to close a column and start a new column

$cluster_current = null;
?>
   <div id="col-1">
<?php
while ($x < $y) {

$name=mysql_result($resultc,$i,"name");
$url=mysql_result($resultc,$i,"url");
$cluster=mysql_result($resultc,$i,"cluster");

  if ($cluster != $cluster_current) {
  $x=$x+1;
?>
</p>
<br>
<h2><?php echo $cluster; ?> Cluster</h2>
<p>
<?php
}
?>
<a href="<?php  echo $url; ?>" class="fade"><?php  echo $name; ?></a><br>
<?php
$i=$i+1;
$cluster_current=mysql_result($resultc,$j,"cluster");
$j=$j+1;
}
?>
   </div>
   <div id="col-2">
<?php
while ($x < $z) {

$name=mysql_result($resultc,$i,"name");
$url=mysql_result($resultc,$i,"url");
$cluster=mysql_result($resultc,$i,"cluster");

  if ($cluster != $cluster_current) {
  $x=$x+1;
?>
</p>
<br>
<h2><?php echo $cluster; ?> Cluster</h2>
<p>
<?php
}
?>
<a href="<?php  echo $url; ?>" class="fade"><?php  echo $name; ?></a><br>
<?php
$i=$i+1;
$cluster_current=mysql_result($resultc,$j,"cluster");
$j=$j+1;
}
?>
   </div>
   <div id="col-3">
<?php
while ($x < $numd) {

$name=mysql_result($resultc,$i,"name");
$url=mysql_result($resultc,$i,"url");
$cluster=mysql_result($resultc,$i,"cluster");

  if ($cluster != $cluster_current) {
$x=$x+1;
?>
</p>
<br>
<h2><?php echo $cluster; ?> Cluster</h2>
<p>
<?php
}
?>
<a href="<?php  echo $url; ?>" class="fade"><?php  echo $name; ?></a><br>
<?php
$i=$i+1;
$cluster_current=mysql_result($resultc,$j,"cluster");
$j=$j+1;
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with PHP, but I know that [there are](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) associative arrays there (dictionaries). This is enough to solve your problem.

First, I'd go with this query (using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)):

```sql
SELECT cluster,
       GROUP_CONCAT(
           CONCAT('<a href="', url, '">', name, '</a>')
       ) AS block
FROM walkthroughs
GROUP BY cluster
```

After you retrieved this put the query response into a dictionary `cluster => block` and then you can iterate thorugh clusters and just `echo` blocks of HTML in the appropriate place on the page.

Comment: I appreciate the direction. After looking at the PHP array link, one or two examples of sql arrays, using your query, and eliminating any commas separating each block result, issue has been solved.

Comment: @user2901346 if my answer helped you, you could mark it as a correct answer.